# Call to undefined relationship [department] on model [App\\Models\\User] in Laravel API

Tags: laravel, api

In my Laravel-8 application, I am building Users API:

In the users model, I have this relations:

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Organization\OrgCompany');
}

public function employee(){
    return $this->hasOne(HrEmployee::class, 'user_id');
}
```

While in Employee relationship I have:

```
public function gradelevel()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\HrGradeLevel','grade_level_id','id');
} 

public function department()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\HrDepartment','department_id','id');
}
```

Then my Controller looks like this:

```
public function userAll()
{
    try{
        if(!Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo('user_access'))
        {
            return response()->json([ "message" => 'You are not authorised to view Users'], 401);
        }
        return response()->json(User::with('employee','company','department','gradelevel')->get(), 200);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        Log::error($e);
        $message = $e->getMessage();
        return response()->json(['error' => 1, 'message' => $message]);
        }
}
```

When I tried to test it in POSTMAN, I got this error:

> "message": "Call to undefined relationship [department] on model [App\Models\User]."

How do I access department and gradelevel relations that are not directly link to users but to employees?

Thanks

Comment: You need to define the `department` relation on User model, you defined it on Employee model

Comment: If User models has a relation with Employee model, then you can do this :  `User::with('employee','company','employee.department','emloyee.gradelevel')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct Syntax is:

```
User::with(['company', 'employee.department', 'employee.gradelevel'])->get();
```

Nested relationship loading uses `.` notation (relationship, other.nested, etc etc). If you load a nested relationship, it loads the parent too, so you don't have to do `['company', 'employee', 'employee.department', 'employee.gradelevel']`

See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading for full details.

Answer (score 1):

With you want to include nested relationships using `with()`. You should use dot annotation, to declare the path of the relationship.

```
with('employee.department', 'employee.gradelevel', 'company')
```